# How can I execute a simple request with an URL in Groovy/Java?

Tags: groovy, httpbuilder

I have the following code in groovy:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://localhost:8080' )
http.post( path: '/this/is/my/path/'+variable) { resp ->
   println "POST Success: ${resp.statusLine}"
   assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200
}
```

I only want to execute that request. I have a method  in another application that when there is a request in that url, I see a result. Problem is that I see nothing.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your application only responds to `GET` request and not to `POST` requests. Try `GET` instead:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://localhost:8080' )
http.get( path: '/this/is/my/path/'+variable) { resp ->
    println "GET Success: ${resp.statusLine}"
    assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200
}
```

Also, are you sure that you expect a HTTP status 201 (Created) at this URL?

Comment: Thanks for the status correction, but I continue without no response with the get

Answer (score 0):

Could try just opening a simple `HttpURLConnection` like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/this/is/my/path/${variable}")
HttpURLConnection connection = url.openConnection()
println "responseCode: ${connection.responseCode}" 
assert connection.responseCode == 200
```